# Use Axios inside service in Nuxt (Vue)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, nuxt.js

I am trying to use nuxt's configured axios instance in service in Nuxt project like this:

```
import axios from 'axios';

export default {
  async create (user) {
     axios.post('/api/user', { user })
  }
}
```

I have defined interceptor in `plugins` folder which add token to header of each request:

```
export default ({ $axios, store }) => {
  $axios.onRequest((config) => {
    if (store.token) {
      config.headers.common.Authorization = store.token
    }
  })
}
```

When I use axios in service as I showed request doesn't contain Authorization header.

If I call axios method in components or vuex like this `this.$axios` then request contains requried header. But this way doesn't work in service because if I use `this.$axios` in service I got `undefined`. What is correct way to use configured axios in services in Nuxt or make it injectable in services?

Comment: I don't see a custom Axios instance in the code you mentioned. That just imports the `axios` package.

Comment: @tony19 this was the only thing that allows me to use axios here. In components and store, I am using this.$axios ... which don't work in custom components like this service, so that is reason why I asked this question

Answer (score 6):

The problem is that you import axios directly from `axios` but the plugin `@nuxtjs/axios` creates a new instance to use nuxt specific config options (a closer look to `./node_modules/@nuxtjs/axios/lib/plugin.js` shows `const axios = Axios.create(axiosOptions)`). Therefore you have to use this instance to get access to the Authorization header.

So you have to register your service as a [nuxt plugin](https://nuxtjs.org/guide/plugins) too and inject your functionality. Please have a look at an untested example but it shows an approach I use in some of my custom plugins:

```js
export default function ({ $axios }, inject) {
  
  const myService = {
    async create (user) {
      $axios.post('/api/user', { user })
    }
  }

  // Will be available in the components as this.$myService
  inject('myService', myService)

}
```

Answer (score 0):

[RWAM](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64503014/17208283)'s answer helped me, but I had to write it like this (kept it simple for the example):

```
export default function ({ $axios }, inject) {
  
  const myService = async (user) => {
      await $axios.post('/api/user', { user })
  }

  // Will be available in the components as this.$myService
  inject('myService', myService)

}
```